# How to add items in listview in wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am trying to add my items in listview. Here is my classes;

```
   FindFace.Show.Response response = await _api.Show_Face(lb_GalleryList.SelectedItem.ToString());        
   if (response.results.Count != 0)
   {
      List<FaceImages> faceImages = new List<FaceImages>();
      for (int i = 0; i < response.results.Count; i++)
      {
         faceImages.Add(new FaceImages() { Face_id = response.results[i].person_id.ToString(), Face_thumbnail = LoadImage(response.results[i].thumbnail) });
      }
      lv_Photos.ItemsSource = faceImages;                    
   }
```

In faceImages, here is what it looks like;
[image]

And also here is my xaml file looks like;

```
<ListView x:Name="lv_Photos" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Face_thumbnail}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Face_id}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

However when I tried to put faceImages to ItemsSource in here;

```
lv_Photos.ItemsSource = faceImages;
```

Application gives

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.
```

I didnt understand how I can pass faceImages class to my listview element.

Comment: You have something in ListView.Items (so for example you manually added some items in ListView in xaml or somehow added something to Items collection in code before), so you cannot use ItemsSource, because Items and ItemsSource are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Evk I am trying to find some solution for this case, I can rewrite everything if necessary.

Comment: also should be using ObservableCollection not List as itemSource or binding wont update

Comment: If you don't ever remove or add items to collection but only update it as a whole (like in your example) - you don't need ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have accidentally added your `DataTemplate` into `ListView` itself, as a child item. That's why `Items` collection is not empty and `ItemsSource` cannot be used, since they are mutually exclusive. Instead, use `ListView.ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv_Photos"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="5"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image Source="{Binding Face_thumbnail}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Face_id}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```